# "Надо" и "нужно"

Tags: стилистика

Есть ли какая-то разница в оттенках смысла слов "надо" и "нужно"? Или они совершенно взаимозаменяемы в тексте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большой разницы в значении и употреблении этих двух слов я не вижу, как не видит ее, например, С. Ожегов. Небольшое семантическое отличие, мне кажется, связано с тем, что слово "нужно" коррелирует с "нужда", "нуждаться", а значит, обозначает более сильную потребность в чем-либо. И еще. У Ожегова есть интересное замечание: слово "надо" можно употребить в таком восклицании междометного характера, как "Надо же!"

Answer (score 1):

В словарях:

- нужно — необходимо что-нибудь сделать или иметь;
- надо — ***разг.*** нужно, необходимо (стилевые различия).

Есть, впрочем, альтернативная версия:

- нужно — о том, чего не хватает;
- надо — о том, чего нет.

И даже такая [альтернативная версия](http://kompotique.ru/nado-i-nuzhno/).

Answer (score 1):

«Нужно» и «Надо» почти равны и часто взаимозаменяемы, но первое указывает на необходимость наличия чего-либо, второе говорит о необходимости сделать нечто: «нужно нечто» и «надо (купить,  принести,  достать) это нечто». Что нужно (цель) и как надо поступить (способ), чтобы задачу решить, — в этом их разница, хотя обозначить задачу и способ можно короче, минуя «надо»: «нужно (купить,  принести,  достать) нечто».  В свою очередь «надо» не всегда может заменять «нужно» как разговорный его вариант. Например в выражении «Это нам надо».

Отдельно употребляемые как утверждение оба слова означают необходимость: «есть такое слово — надо».

Comment: С началом согласен на все сто! Если "Это нам надо" пример неправильного употребления, то и это полностью поддерживаю. Удивляюсь, почему я за cotique когда-то проголосовал (читаю её ответ и не врубаюсь сейчас), а за вас нет.